# Передача WordDocument по сслыке

Tags: c#, функции, ms-word

Пытаюсь передать WordWocument в функцию по ссылке:

```
 private void ReplaseWordStub(string stubToReplace,string text,ref Word.Documents wordDocument)
    {
        var range = wordDocument.Content;
        range.Find.ClearFormatting();

    }
```

Но метод Content компилятором не определяется.

Если все тоже самое сделать в том-же методе, то компилируется.

```
 public void WriteToDoc(String stubToReplace, string text)
        {
            var wordApp = new Word.Application(); //создаем приложение word
            wordApp.Visible = false; //скрываем от пользователя
            var wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(PatchToFile);//открываем файл

            var range = wordDocument.Content;
            range.Find.ClearFormatting();
            range.Find.Execute(FindText:stubToReplace,ReplaceWith:text);

        }
```

Как корректро передать wordDocument по ссылке?

Answer (score 0):

Правильная передача:

```
  public void WriteToDoc(String stubToReplace, string text)
    {
        try
        {

            var wordApp = new Word.Application(); //создаем приложение word
            wordApp.Visible = false; //скрываем от пользователя
            var wordDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(PatchToFile); //открываем файл

            ReplaseWordStub(stubToReplace,text,wordDocument);
            wordDocument.SaveAs("@E:\\Dropbox\\C#\\TestManager\\Rezult.docx");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }


    private void ReplaseWordStub(string stubToReplace, string text, Word.Document wordDocument)
        {

            var range = wordDocument.Content;
            range.Find.ClearFormatting();
            range.Find.Execute(FindText: stubToReplace, ReplaceWith: text);

        }
```